# How to drag and drop collection view cell from 1 to another uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uipangesturerecognizer

Here the scenario.

I have a `UITableView` With Multiple Section. Each Section Contains exact 1 row.
And each row contains a `UICollectionView`.

```
----------------------------------
TablViewSection 1
----------------------------------
|--------------| |--------------|
|  Collection  | |  Collection  |
|   View Cell  | |   View Cell  |
|--------------| |--------------|

----------------------------------
TablViewSection 2
----------------------------------
|--------------| |--------------|
|  Collection  | |  Collection  |
|   View Cell  | |   View Cell  |
|--------------| |--------------|
```

This is how it is like.

This is working perfect.

But here is what i want to do : I want to drag `CollectionViewCell` of First section to second section's `UICollectionView`.

I applied `PanGesture` on `CollectionViewCell` and below is the selector method of panGesture. Using below code I am able to drag collection view cell but not able to drop to second section's collection view.

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {

    UICollectionView *collectionViewRef =   [[panRecognizer view] superview];

    CGPoint locationPoint = [panRecognizer locationInView:[[panRecognizer view] superview]];

    UICollectionViewCell *cellRef = [panRecognizer view];

    if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPathOfMovingCell = [collectionViewRef indexPathForItemAtPoint:locationPoint];
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionViewRef cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPathOfMovingCell];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size);
        [cell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    //        [self.movingCell setCenter:locationPoint];
              [cellRef setCenter:locationPoint];
    }

    if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //        [self.movingCell removeFromSuperview];
              [cellRef removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Because items are draggable inside its own parent only.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** My answer is a bit late but if that helps someone it could be great !

---

I've done it some day, and it was quite hard...

You need to do something like that :

`CGRect frame = [self.collectionView convertRect:draggedCell.frame toView:self.view];`

To convert the points of the dragged cell to the parent view and then calculate where you are on the screen.

After that you need to copy/paste the data of your cell at the new position.

Hope it was a litle bit helpfull.

If I'm wrong or I missunderstood the question do not hesitate to let me know.